# How to set a custom platform in Dialogflow NodeJS Client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have created a webhook using [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) to correctly return different data depending on the platform, including a custom one I created for another service. I've tested my webhook and know that if I change the `originalDetectIntentRequest.source` to the platform used in my custom payload it works.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "jokes-api": {
            "success": true,
            "text": "These are some jokes",
        }
    },
    "outputContexts": []
}
```

I am able to use [dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2)'s `sessions.detectIntent` to get a response, but the fullfilment comes back with the platform set as `PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED`, and not the custom payloads I want.

```
[{
    "responseId": "c56c462f-bb3b-434a-b318-3739f58e6f6d",
    "queryResult": {
        "fulfillmentMessages": [{
            "platform": "PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED",
            "card": {
                "buttons": [],
                "title": "Jokes",
                "subtitle": "These are some jokes",
                "imageUri": ""
            },
            "message": "card"
        }],
        "queryText": "tell me a joke",
        /* ... */
        "intent": {
            "name": "projects/my-jokes/agent/intents/56887375-3047-4993-8e14-53b20dd02697",
            "displayName": "Jokes",
            /* ... */
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.8999999761581421,
    }
}]
```

Looking at the logs for my webhook, I can see that the `originalDetectIntentRequest` object is present, but source is not set.

```
{
  "responseId": "c56c462f-bb3b-434a-b318-3739f58e6f6d",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "tell me a joke",
    "speechRecognitionConfidence": 0.9602501,
    /* ... */
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/my-jokes/agent/intents/56887375-3047-4993-8e14-53b20dd02697",
      "displayName": "Jokes"
    },
    /* ... */
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {
    }
  },
  "session": "projects/my-jokes/agent/sessions/12345"
}
```

How can I set the platform or source in dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2 to get the desired responses?

Answer (score 10):

`sessions.detectIntent` API has `queryParams` parameter which has a field called `payload`. That's where the "original payload" goes. The name of the platform goes into the `source` field of that structure. So your `detectIntent` call should look something like this:

```
sessionClient.detectIntent({
    session: sessionClient.sessionPath('<project_id>', '<session_id>'),
    queryInput: {
        text: {
            text: '<query>',
            languageCode: 'en-US'
        }
    },
    queryParams: {
        payload: {
            fields: {
                source: {
                    stringValue: '<platform>',
                    kind: 'stringValue'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I was able to simulate Slack integration call by using 'slack' as a platform name. I was also able to return a custom payload for a custom platform name. The payload is returned in `queryResult.webhookPayload` field.

Comment: Thanks! Note that you can also use structjson to write your payload as explained there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583996/send-parameters-to-webhook-on-dialogflow-sdk-v2

Comment: I want to get outputAudio JSON in the response, which source should I specify?