# Error: Platform can NOT be empty at new Payload in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have a serverless app where I want to run my logic from the chatbot request coming from Facebook Messenger. When I run the intent function for **test_handler** I get the correct response back. But after I added another handler for **skillRatio** I seem to be getting the error in the title i.e

> Error: Platform can NOT be empty at new Payload

. My code is as below.

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict: false }));

const {WebhookClient, Payload, Image, Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const request = require('request');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World !!!\n');
  console.log("Testing express lambda\n");
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({request: req, response: res});

    function test_handler(agent) {
      agent.add(`Welcome to my agent on AWS Lambda!`);
      agent.add(new Image("https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=700x190&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello%7CWorld&chf=ps0-0,lg,45,ffeb3b,0.2,f44336,1|ps0-1,lg,45,8bc34a,0.2,009688,1"))
    }

    function skillRatio(agent) {
      agent.add(`Let me just have a look and I'll gather the data. *Processing Chart Data....Mmmm Pie*. 
        Here we go! Here is the data on your $Skills.original request.`);
      //agent.add(`Feel free to save or share :)`);
      //agent.add(new Image("https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=700x190&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello%7CWorld&chf=ps0-0,lg,45,ffeb3b,0.2,f44336,1|ps0-1,lg,45,8bc34a,0.2,009688,1"))
    }

    // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('super-test', test_handler);
    //intentMap.set('skill-ratio', skillRatio);

    if (agent.requestSource === agent.FACEBOOK) {
      intentMap.set('super-test', test_handler);
      intentMap.set('skill-ratio', skillRatio);
    } else {

    }

    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
})
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Dialogflow Images:

[image: Training Phrases]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to run the code on Messenger. Any help would be hugely appreciated as I am so stuck trying to get my head around this.

Comment: Can you update your question with a screen shot of your `skillRatio` Intent screen in Dialogflow? I also see you're testing for `agent.FACEBOOK` specifically. What happens if you uncomment the `intentMap.set()` for skill-ratio and remove this if block?

Comment: Prisoner, I sure can, bare with me. Do you just want to see the Phrases? Thanks a million for the fast reply also! I tried to test for agent.FACEBOOK as I felt it was looking specifically for a Platform. But I could see in AWS CloudWatch that Facebook was already set. Nothing happens when I uncomment the skill-ratio mapping. I get the error in my logs when trying to call it.

Comment: Seeing all sections of the entire Intent can help pick up if the problem was with something besides the phrases - so please include everything if you can.

Comment: Perfect will add the rest. There wasn't anything else really to the intent other than the switch for Fulfilment. I'll add the other photos also.

Comment: I'm actually really annoyed with myself. It turns out that the default payload on the Dialogflow image was causing the issue. Twice I thought I could remove it but thought it was too small to be the issue. The code works fine now after I removed the Custom Payload. Sorry about the confusion but maybe this might help others in the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was gonna ask about that - good catch! Go ahead and write that as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: (But that's why I asked to post everything. {: )

Comment: Hahah that's true xD. Thanks a million though, the fast response helped me to keep at it :)

Comment: (And I'm serious - write it up as an answer rather than a comment. It will help others with the same problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, in the below image, a Custom Payload was causing the issue I was having. If you get the same error

> Error: Platform can NOT be empty at new Payload.

Triple check your default responses across all the response types and remove anything that has an empty payload.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your resolution is a little intuitive and not completely correct. It is not specifically a problem with an empty payload, the problem persists with having a payload in general.

You can try to either set the platform manually like so =>
[How to set a custom platform in Dialogflow NodeJS Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096251/how-to-set-a-custom-platform-in-dialogflow-nodejs-client)

or choose one of the methods described in here =>
https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/153

Setting the platform befor initializing the WebHookClient

```
if (!request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages)
    return;
request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages = request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages.map(m => {
    if (!m.platform)
        m.platform = 'PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED';
    return m;
});
```