# How to set query parameters dialogflow php sdk

Tags: php, json, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I want to send queryParameters , mostly the payload on dialogflow so i can get it on google cloud function.

I've tried

```
private function getPayload(ChatbotDialog $dialog): Struct
    {
        $data = '{
                  "fields" : {
                    "source" : {
                        "stringValue" : "platform",
                        "kind" : "stringValue"
                    }
                  }
        }';
        $payload = new Struct();
        $payload->mergeFromJsonString($data);
        return $payload;
    }

$queryParam = new QueryParameters();       
$queryParam->setPayload($this->getPayload($dialog));
```

but it seem it does not work the `originalDetectIntentRequest` is always empty on cloud function.

I've seen that : [Send parameters to webhook on dialogflow sdk v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583996/send-parameters-to-webhook-on-dialogflow-sdk-v2)

but they use `queryInput.event` and i use `queryInput.text` so the solution does not work.

Comment: I found the solution , i was setting `$optionalsParams = ['queryParameters' => $queryParam];` instead of  `$optionalsParams = ['queryParams' => $queryParam];`
Before :
`$response = $sessionsClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput, $optionalsParams);`

Comment: You saved my day! I mentioned your post in my question because I struggled to find it. Hope others will find it more easily now : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557233/dialogflow-v2-api-how-to-pass-context-and-or-payload-php