# How to get custom payload response from dialogflow to API in PHP

Tags: php, api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Getting only text response for the intent but the custom payload response is missing in api response.

Dialogflow raw response is [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2yxH.png)

```
{
"allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
"fulfillmentText": "Thanks Dhruva, are you ?",
"fulfillmentMessages": [
  {
    "text": {
      "text": [
        "Thanks Dhruva, are you ?"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "payload": {
      "richContent": [
        [
          {
            "type": "chips",
            "options": [
              {
                "text": "permanent employee"
              },
              {
                "text": "probation employee"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
}
```

Api receiving only text not custom payload [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdl8W.png)

Took a reference from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557233/dialogflow-v2-api-how-to-pass-context-and-or-payload-php) but was unable to fix either, any help or point to the right direction will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you using any library of Dialogflow in your PHP code?

Comment: yes, installed the dialogflow component of Google Cloud Client Libraries with

~composer require google/cloud-dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the custom payload in a php associative array

```
        $textInput = new TextInput();
        $textInput->setText($request->query("message","message that has custom payload response"));
        $textInput->setLanguageCode("en-US");

        //Putting it in query input
        $queryInput = new QueryInput();
        $queryInput->setText($textInput);
        $response = $sessionClient->detectIntent($session, $queryInput);
        $queryResult = $response->getQueryResult();

        //Beginning of solution
        $fulfillmentMessages = $queryResult->getFulfillmentMessages();
        $customPayloads = []; //The result array

        foreach ($fulfillmentMessages as $fulfillmentMessage) {
            /* @var $fulfillmentMessage Message*/
            if($fulfillmentMessage->hasPayload()) {
                $customPayloads[] = json_decode($fulfillmentMessage->getPayload()
                    ->serializeToJsonString(),1);
            }
        }
```