# Convert JSON object to protobuf IStruct

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

I am using the [Dialogflow API for Nodejs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/dialogflow/0.8.x/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2).

This API is apparently implemented by Google via protocol buffers, though it presents a simple JavaScript/JSON based interface that I have used successfully for simple queries.

In order to request Dialogflow send me response data for a particular platform, [I apparently need](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/issues/132#issuecomment-406210509) to encode a simple JSON object into protobuf format. The linked source gives an example that makes use of a "structjson util" that can presumably be used to do the necessary conversion:

```
const structjson = require('./structjson.js');

const request = {
    /* other properties omitted */
    queryParams: {
        payload: structjson.jsonToStructProto({source: 'ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE'})
    },
};
```

Unfortunately, the link given for the structjson util is dead, and I can find no other reference to it.

I don't need to do anything other than encode a simple JSON object, as per the example above. Is there a simple utility (either runtime or command line) that can be used to do that without having to do major surgery with the protobuf toolchain?

Comment: found the file in history https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/d907f3af57438c3e88c274b100eab520b5b51062/samples/structjson.js

Comment: thanks @karthick that's very helpful. I've also found that the samples were updated to use a new library for the conversion; I'll follow up with an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the Google Dialogflow samples were [updated](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/pull/311/files) to use the [pb-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pb-util) package for JSON-to-protobuf conversions. This package provides a method for [encoding JSON to protobuf](https://github.com/callmehiphop/pb-util#structencodejson) easily, so the example from the original question simply becomes:

```
const {struct} = require('pb-util');

const request = {
    /* other properties omitted */
    queryParams: {
        payload: struct.encode({source: 'ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE'})
    },
};
```

Thanks also to @karthick for locating the [original structjson file](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/d907f3af57438c3e88c274b100eab520b5b51062/samples/structjson.js) in the Dialogflow samples repo.